# Does periodic short polling scale on the server?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, comet

We are developing a site that will allow users to send semi-real-time events to other users.  The UI will display an icon when there is a new event for a user (pretty standard stuff).

I have read that periodic short polling does not scale as well as websockets because it puts more pressure on the web server.  I am not quite sure why this would be the case?

We are using tomcat NIO (which does not have a one-to-one connection per thread ratio).  As I understand it, Tomcat NIO is pretty good at handling longer HTTP connection timeouts with a small number of threads.

So, if the periodic polling time is less than the connection timeout, then the polling should not have to create another TCP handshake, as it will just reuse an existing HTTP 1.1 connection.

Thus, the above does not seem like it would create too much pressure on the server.  It may not be as real-time as long polling or websockets, but I do not see why it should not scale (assuming that the server can quickly respond with a response indicating a new event or not – we use an in memory concurrent hashmap, so this should be pretty fast with no necessary DB access).

Am I missing anything?

Thanks,
-Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short polling may not be as trendy as long polling and web sockets but it works and works everywhere.

Trello (backed by some of the same people as SO) normally uses web sockets but when they encountered a crippling bug in their web sockets implementation on launch day they were saved by short polling:

> We hit a problem right after launch. Our WebSocket server implementation started behaving very strangely under the sudden and heavy real-world usage of launching at TechCrunch disrupt, and we were glad to be able to revert to plain polling and tune server performance by adjusting the active and idle polling intervals. It allowed us to degrade gracefully as we increased from 300 to 50,000 users in under a week. We’re back on WebSockets now, but having a working short-polling system still seems like a very prudent fallback.

The full [story](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/) is well worth a read.

I'd particularly highlight,

1. The use of HAProxy to terminate the client connection.  Meaning that internal web servers are shielded from slow and misbehaving clients and the overhead of repeatedly creating connections becomes less of an issue due to HAProxy's scalability/efficiency;
2. Trello's polling frequency was adjustable meaning that under heavy load they could tell all clients to poll less frequently thus exchanging responsiveness for increased capacity.

In Brazil at least there are many retail trading platforms that use short polling, with very short polling intervals for rapid publication of stock prices, and  regularly support thousands of concurrent users.

Unlike long polling and web sockets, short polling doesn't require a persistent connection so with something like HAProxy in the middle your maximum number of "connections" could actually be greater than the number of concurrent sockets supported by your hardware (although at that point you'd probably be seeing some degradation in responsiveness).

Comment: Does this mean with a powerful server, short polling will be able to handle up to 50,000 users?

Comment: For 50k users you're probably talking 3-5 servers, but that really depends on your hardware & code.

Comment: Could you check my question and help me with an approximation. Thanks :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314203/approximately-how-many-users-can-short-polling-handle-with-1-server

Comment: @almostabeginner I wrote 3-5 servers assuming you'd want near real-time updates (say every 250ms). I saw your question but it was deleted before I could answer.  If you're only updating every 20s you'll be fine with 1 server.  I've seen 1 server supporting 10k+ users with updates every 250ms.  It's important that the code that runs when you call poll is lightening fast (ideally, only checking memory.  You could have a background process or pub-sub keeping that memory up-to date).

Comment: someone downvoted and asked my question to be closed on basis of it being too broad. Anyways, this answer really clarifies alot for me, thanks.